# ¿Qué es un "taxi zapatico" en Colombia?

Tags: coloquialismos, adjetivos, colombia

El otro día topé con la noticia [Mujer encontró a su hermana y a su esposo en motel de Ibagué](http://rubendariocorrea.com/wpsite/mujer-encontro-a-su-hermana-y-a-su-esposo-en-motel-de-ibague/). Es de una periódico local colombiano que se nutre de historias variopintas y bueno... sí, no es muy serio pero reconozco que  estos cotilleos siempre entretienen.

La noticia hablaba de un lance de infidelidad amorosa que terminó como el rosario de la aurora: el marido fue descubierto y huyó como pudo. En concreto, lo explicaba así:

> A los pocos minutos un **taxi zapatico** ingresó y evacuó al hombre con rumbo desconocido.

Me sorprendió el uso de *zapatico* aquí. Para mí, en España, un zapatico es un diminutivo de zapato. Sin embargo, por contexto no puede ser eso.

Busqué un rato y encontré que hay un modelo de Suzuki llamado Zapatico, bastante viejo, que aparece en bastantes páginas de compra venta de coches de Colombia:

[image]

Sin embargo, busqué luego por *taxi zapatico* y me salieron imágenes de este tipo:

[image]

Que coincide con el tipo de taxis que predominan en ese país. Sin embargo, estos ya no son de ese modelo ni seguramente esa marca (creo que eran híbridos, pero no recuerdo la marca). En España, a estos los solemos llamar *coche huevo* por pequeños y redonditos.

Así pues, ¿qué es un *zapatico*? ¿Se usa solamente como adjetivo del taxi? ¿Será que el modelo Zapatico tuvo tanta fama que pasó a designar un tipo de coche?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente la segunda imagen de tu pregunta es lo que algunos denominan taxi zapatico y la simple razón es porque algunos le ven el parecido a un zapato.

Los dos tipos de taxis más comunes en Colombia tienen casi la misma forma y son el Chevrolet Chronos (la versión no taxi es Chevrolet Spark) y el Hyundai i10 o Hyundai Atos (cuyas versiones no taxi tienen el mismo nombre).

Ambos siguen siendo los tipos más comunes por ser económicos y pequeños para sortear el pesado tráfico de ciudades grandes.

Contrario a lo que dice otra respuesta el modelo sí es muy exitoso y existen miles de estos vehículos tanto en su versión taxi como particular, ya que son el carro más barato del mercado y uno de los que menos combustible consume. Para validar esto es suficiente mirar las imágenes del [reciente paro de taxistas](http://www.eltiempo.com/colombia/otras-ciudades/paro-de-taxistas-en-colombia-contra-la-plataforma-uber-86530) y apreciar que 9 de cada 10 vehículos es de este tipo

[image: Chevrolet Chronos]

[image: Hyundai i10]

Comment: ¿Decimos _uno de los que menos combustible consume_ o _uno de los que menos combustible consume**n**_? Me entró la duda.

Comment: @fedorqui a mi también me entró la duda. Uso el singular porque estoy individualizando el mejor y debería haber concordancia de numero entre "es uno"y "consume", pero podría usar el plural si dijera "Es uno entre aquellos que conumenN menos". Creo que deberías hacer una pregunta para que los expertos nos ayuden. :-)

Comment: Me lo apunto en la lista de "preguntas por hacer" :)

Answer (score 3):

Parece ser que un "zapatico" es un "[tipo de carro pequeño](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/29751-zapatico)".

En este artículo sobre [los peligros de este tipo de coches](http://www.pulzo.com/nacion/por-que-son-tan-peligrosos-los-taxis-zapatico-que-circulan-en-colombia/371651) se explica que

> Los ‘zapaticos’ se caracterizan por tener no un compartimento de baúl independiente.

que entiendo que significa que no tiene "habitáculos independientes" y que en caso de colisión los pasajeros pueden recibir un golpe de la estructura cuando esta se deforma.

Aquí hay [otro artículo](https://www.las2orillas.co/la-inseguridad-de-los-taxis-zapaticos/) sobre lo mismo. Es interesante *(y alarmante)* que todo lo que he conseguido encontrar en la red se refiere a que los zapaticos son autos compactos, pero veo la palabra casi siempre asociada a *taxis* y a los problemas de seguridad de este tipo de autos. ["Una tumba con llantas", según este artículo](http://blogs.eltiempo.com/todo-sobre-autos/2015/07/09/aun-nos-venden-carros-nuevos-muy-inseguros-en-choque-frontal/) donde un usuario comenta

> casi el 70 % de los taxis en Colombia son de los llamados “zapatico”, que no aguantan un choque de frente, ni de lado, ni por detrás, ni por encima. son como cáscara de huevo.

Por lo que entiendo que `zapatico` es una manera coloquial de denominar un auto pequeño *(y posiblemente económico, viendo las carencias del mi*smo), no necesariamente un taxi, pero este modelo es mucho más frecuente en taxis.

Comment: Efectivamente asi es... tal vez incluso más del 70% de los taxis tienen esa forma.

Answer (score 3):

En Colombia se denomina "zapatico" a cualquier automóvil que visto de perfil tenga la forma de un zapato pequeño, semejante al zapato que usaría un bebé (de allí proviene la expresión).

El modelo no fue muy famoso, no es un carro que se encuentre en grandes cantidades en las ciudades de Colombia, la expresión aplica también para automóviles particulares con ese tipo de forma, no es exclusiva para taxis aunque sí es la más común.

Comment: Por el contrario es el modelo más famoso y este tipo de carros se encuentra en grandes cantidades en las grandes ciudades. Solo mira las imagenes del reciente paro de taxistas y verás que 9 de cada 10 taxis es un Chronos o un i10 (http://www.eltiempo.com/colombia/otras-ciudades/paro-de-taxistas-en-colombia-contra-la-plataforma-uber-86530)

Comment: El modelo al que hace referencia cuando habla del "modelo zapatico" es al del Suzuki.Es cierto que los taxis en forma de "zapatico" son los más comunes, por otro lado los "Suzuki zapatico" son carros poco comunes por lo cual es poco probable que se popularizara el nombre a partir de ese modelo de automóvil.

Comment: Mi duda al comprar tu respuesta y la de @DGaleano es si _Suzuki Zapatico_ fue un modelo con ese nombre comercial o si el adjetivo se puso por su forma. Parece lo segundo, ¿no?

Comment: Fue un adjetivo que se le puso por la forma que tiene, el nombre del modelo es Suzuki Fronte Coupe.

Answer (score 0):

Un Taxi Zapatico, o un taxi chiquito, es un tipo de taxi que se ve mucho, pero mucho por acá en Colombia.

¿Por qué?

Porque en Colombia a nadie le importa que estos carritos no sean aptos para el transporte público. (Hay que ver las pruebas de colisión de estos carritos, en serio) Hay varios lugares del mundo donde no son permitidos.

Porque como son chiquitos pueden "culebrear" entre el tráfico.

Porque aunque son peligrosos son BARATOS

Existe un grupo de Facebook. "odio los taxis chiquitos"

Ah, y usualmente no tienen baúl (está ocupado por el cilindro de gas).

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta (**por qué se le llama "zapatico"**) y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!